# Running hg command in c#

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd, mercurial

I have create a C# application for make easy of committing changes to mercurial repository. i have use following code to run hg commands in c# process

```
  static void ExecuteCMDCommand(string path, string command)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            //startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = "hg.exe";
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = command;
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            try
            {

                myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;

                var sbOut = new StringBuilder();
                var sbErr = new StringBuilder();

                var sw = new Stopwatch();

                sw.Start();

                myProcess.Start();

                TimeSpan firstRead = TimeSpan.Zero;

                myProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (firstRead == TimeSpan.Zero)
                    {
                        firstRead = sw.Elapsed;
                    }                    
                    sbOut.Append(e.Data);
                };
                Console.WriteLine("**************" + sbOut.ToString());

                myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => sbErr.Append(e.Data);

                myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

                var eventsStarted = sw.Elapsed;

                myProcess.WaitForExit();

                var processExited = sw.Elapsed;

                sw.Reset();

               // string strOutput = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally {
                myProcess.Close();
                myProcess.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

this works for **hg status/hg branches** but when i execute **hg pull** it is not working, i only see pulling from **http://abc.abc.com/hg/repo**. 
What should i do for this?

Comment: What do you expect `hg pull` to do instead of pulling from the repository?

Comment: yes, i expected pull from repository. it should ask for user name and password. that line not come, UI get stuck and remain